# Selecting Value from Combobox and display the corresponding value in a Textbox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox

I have a program where in I have to select a value in a combo box and automatically display its corresponding value to a textbox.

The program goes like this:
I will select a product ID in combobox = 'skucbo' and then the Product Description will be displayed automatically in a textbox = 'descriptiontxt'.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub descriptiontxt_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles descriptiontxt.TextChanged

    Dim sku As String = skucbo.SelectedValue.ToString
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    connect()
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT description FROM tbl_sku WHERE skucbo = @sku"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Hoping for your response. Thanks!

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: I think you want your code in "comboBox_changed" event. When the combo changes you change your text. Also you should load descriptions and not hit the database every time the combo changes (assuming your list is relatively small).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make a SelectedIndexChanged for your combobox.
And in the SelectedIndexChanged you set the textbox to the combobox selected item.

### "descriptiontxt.Text = skucbo.SelectedItem"

```
Private Sub skucbo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles skucbo.SelectedIndexChanged
    descriptiontxt.Text = skucbo.SelectedItem
End Sub
```